# How does the "rubbed" coating of an LCD align liquid crystal molecules?

Tags: lcd, physics

For many LCD applications the liquid crystal layer's relaxed state is a "helix" twisting the alignment from one direction at top to another on the bottom. Obviously, within the liquid crystal layer itself the "aligning" force is the same that causes the molecules to align along a director in general. My question is about the bottom and top layers whose direction is forced by a ["rubbed" polyimide coating](https://www.crystec.com/joyrube.htm) [(additional link)](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~mgu/LCD/tn.htm) (or similar mechanism). What's the nature of how this coating encourages the molecules to have a certain orientation? Does the rubbing cause microgrooves that the (usually elongated) liquid crystal molecules naturally fill? Is the force electrical in nature? Chemical? A combination? The picture from [the first source](https://www.crystec.com/joyrube.htm) implies grooves, but I haven't found any explicit answer.

Comment: Please add a link to your source for "rubbed" polyimide.

Comment: @Transistor Added example sources. Thanks for pointing out the need for that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubbing produces a surface alignment of the molecules in the coating of the electrode. The LC molecules then align with these though Van der Waals inter-molecular forces. Putting it simply the molecules align to find the minimum energy state between the LC molecules and the polyimide molecules.

The alignment is not caused by mechanical grooving. This is clearly shown by the axis of LC molecule alignment not being aligned in the direction in which grooves wold be formed and being different in different materials.

See [this paper](https://www-ssrl.slac.stanford.edu/stohr/jesrp-98-189-99.pdf) for more details.